# How to access local files within project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, bundle

I want to add some static files (image, binary, etc...) to my app.  I've placed them under a folder named `Resources` and have added it to my XCode project.

Next, I have those files added to the `Copy Bundle Resources` in the `Build Phases` tab in the project settings.

However, I can't seem to refer to them in the right way.

For instance, reading a binary file:

```
NSInputStream *is = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:@"data.bin"];
if(![is hasBytesAvailable]) NSLog(@"wrong");
```

This always fails & prints `wrong`

I tried a similar approach with `NSData initWithContentsOfFile:` but this wouldn't even execute.  Another attempt was to use `[NSBundle mainBundle]` but this also didn't execute fully.

I'm new to iOS please help I can access my local files!  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Is the case correct ? iOS is case-sensitive, so `Data.BIN` and `data.bin` are two different files.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to ensure that you're accessing the file in the right place.  Xcode places your resource files in the application's "application bundle" in the **Resources** directory.  There are many ways to dig 'em out.

A common way is to get the pathname of a file in your bundle:

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *myFile = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"data" ofType: @"bin"];
```

If you have other files in nonstandard places in your bundle, there are variations to **pathForResource** that let your specify a directory name.

If you want to see the actual location on your hard-drive that the simulator is using so you can inspect it, you can say:

```
NSLog(@"Main bundle path: %@", mainBundle);
NSLog(@"myFile path: %@", myFile);
```

Search for the "Bundle Programming Guide" in the Xcode documentation library to get started. :-)

Comment: If you're getting errors using the code above (like getting nil back for myFile) find your application bundle in Xcode's build directory, right click it (to view it's contents) and see if Xcode **actually** put the "data.bin" file there. :-)

Comment: indeed it was giving me nil back for `pathForResource` I deleted all my Resources & adding them back from scratch.  what's the best way to add bundles?  do I right-click on the project and do `Add Files to <project.name>?`

Comment: You should just be able to use the "+" button in the "Copy Bundle Resources" part of the Build Phases settings for your target.  Again, if you want to see what Xcode is doing behind the scenes, use the Finder to navigate to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerrivedData/{random lowercase letters} name}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator` and look inside the ".app" file.  That's your bundle, and that should have the files that you asked Xcode to copy.

Comment: Thank you got the path right... but still no luck on creating a valid NSInputStream

Comment: nvm forgot to call `[is open]` after init haha ;-)  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSBundle` class for that. For Example:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"bin"];
NSInputStream *is = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:path];
...
```

Comment: I'm getting *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

Indeed calling [is open] is needed even though you "initialiseWithFileAtPath".  I would think the initialisation would automatically open the file for you, but it doesn't.