# How to access file saved in project folder (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone

I have huge json request from server which took a lot of time , therefore I decided to save it in a text file in the same folder of project . But I do not know how can I read it. Can someone help me in this matter?

Thank you

Comment: Show your code, what you have tried?

Comment: Add it as resource, and load with `NSBundle pathForResource:` and `NSData dataWithContentsOfFile` check answers in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/20795756/1403732

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access local files within project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776536/how-to-access-local-files-within-project)